# java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi, jsf-2.2

Given the following CDI bean in JSF 2.2.6 running on GlassFish server 4.0.

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel;

@ViewScoped
@Named("myBean")
public class MyBean extends LazyDataModel<T> implements Serializable
{
    @Inject   //Injecting an EJB.
    private MyLocalEJB service;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

This causes the following exception to be thrown on undeployment of the application.

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.writeObject(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1518)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.writeObject(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1519)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:2195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.writeSessions(StandardManager.java:761)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.saveSessions(WebModule.java:1730)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.unloadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2430)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.unloadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2386)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.stop(WebApplication.java:190)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.stop(EngineRef.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.stop(ModuleInfo.java:324)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.stop(ApplicationInfo.java:380)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.unload(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1056)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.undeploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1096)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.UndeployCommand.execute(UndeployCommand.java:400)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:537)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.handleRedeploy(DeployCommand.java:724)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:537)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.ReDeployCommand.execute(ReDeployCommand.java:131)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

In JSF 2.2, there is a [`ViewScoped` for CDI beans](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#1087). So, why does this throw this exception?

Also it is Java EE 7 though the IDE (NetBeans 8.0) issues a warning,

> Unsatisfied dependency: no bean matches the injection point

on the following statement in the bean:

```
private MyLocalEJB service;
```

In Java EE 7, there should not be a need to create the `beans.xml` file. So, this warning should not be issued. Is it necessary to create `beans.xml` in Java EE 7 ?

Comment: @unwichtich : T represents any valid class type in Java. It is a [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/org/primefaces/model/LazyDataModel.html) thing and has whatsoever completely nothing to do with the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean

This is a bug in Mojarra. It has been reported as [issue 3191](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3191). It's fixed in Mojarra 2.2.7 whose release is expected [3 july 2014](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES/fixforversion/16868). If you need to get it fixed right now, grab the 2.2.7 snapshot. See for download details the answer on [How to download Mojarra JSF nightly builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763138/how-to-download-mojarra-jsf-nightly-builds).

---

> Also it is Java EE 7 though the IDE (NetBeans 8.0) issues a warning,
>
> > Unsatisfied dependency: no bean matches the injection point

Sorry, Netbeans is beyond me. If you're already using the latest Netbeans version and you are confident that Netbeans is Wrong (i.e. everything just works apart from the particular exception), then you'd report an issue to them.

---

> In Java EE 7, there should not be a need to create the beans.xml file. So, this warning should not be issued.

You're completely right. See also this blog of Reza Rahman: [Default CDI enablement in Java EE 7](http://java.dzone.com/articles/default-cdi-enablement-java-ee).