# java.lang.IllegalStateException: WELD-000340: A request must be associated with the context in order to load the known conversations

Tags: netbeans, wildfly, netbeans-plugins, wildfly-8, netbeans-8

I'm getting the following exception on accessing an XHTML page on WildFly 8.1.0 final.

```
00:46:41,859 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-26) Error Rendering View[/Test.xhtml]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WELD-000340: A request must be associated with the context in order to load the known conversations
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractConversationContext.checkIsAssociated(AbstractConversationContext.java:416) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractConversationContext.getCurrentConversation(AbstractConversationContext.java:431) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.jsf.ConversationAwareViewHandler.getActionURL(ConversationAwareViewHandler.java:110) [weld-core-jsf-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.getActionURL(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:189) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.FormRenderer.getActionStr(FormRenderer.java:231) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.FormRenderer.encodeBegin(FormRenderer.java:134) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:864) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1855) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1860) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1860) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:461) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]

00:46:42,015 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-26) UT005023: Exception handling request to /Test-war/Test.xhtml: javax.servlet.ServletException: WELD-000340: A request must be associated with the context in order to load the known conversations
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WELD-000340: A request must be associated with the context in order to load the known conversations
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractConversationContext.checkIsAssociated(AbstractConversationContext.java:416) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractConversationContext.getCurrentConversation(AbstractConversationContext.java:431) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.jsf.ConversationAwareViewHandler.getActionURL(ConversationAwareViewHandler.java:110) [weld-core-jsf-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.getActionURL(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:189) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.FormRenderer.getActionStr(FormRenderer.java:231) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.FormRenderer.encodeBegin(FormRenderer.java:134) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:864) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1855) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1860) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1860) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:461) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    ... 26 more
```

I do not use any CDI beans in the application (all of them are JSF managed beans).

---

The following is all irrelevant :

[See the linked question instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26447519/1391249)

<s>**EDIT :**</s>

Unfortunately, this happens, when OmniFaces (1.8.1) is added to the classpath **along with PrimeFaces 5.1 final**.

If OminFaces (1.8.1) **alone** is added (without PrimeFaces 5.1 final), then it causes the [this](http://pastebin.com/sgmxvLWu) exception to be thrown (the stacktrace is too long to accommodate in the question body).

The above mentioned exception happens (in the code snippet, not in the pastbin) in the following situation.

Given below a JSF managed bean as an example :

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestManagedBean implements Serializable
{
    private String text;
    private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;
    public TestManagedBean() {}

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Just accessing this bean as follows (from an XHTML page).

```xhtml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:inputText value="#{testManagedBean.text}"/>
            <h:commandButton value="Submit"/>
            <!--This button is not needed any more-->
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

This would throw the exception (if you happened to add OmniFaces (1.8.1 ) along with PrimeFaces (5.1.0 final) to the classpath).

---

The exception vanishes, when the given JSF managed bean is turned into a CDI bean as follows (works fine with or without OmniFaces (1.8.1), if it is a CDI bean).

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestManagedBean implements Serializable
{
    private String text;
    private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;
    public TestManagedBean() {}

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

---

Finally, if `<o:viewParam>` is used on an XHTML page like as follows,

```xhtml
<ui:define name="metaData">
    <f:metadata>
        <o:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.property}"/>
    </f:metadata>
</ui:define>
```

then the following message appears on the server terminal. The name `metaData` is defined on the master page template just like as follows.

```xhtml
<ui:insert name="metaData"></ui:insert>
```

```
01:17:29,000 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-30) JSF1068: Cannot instantiate component with component-type org.omnifaces.component.input.ViewParam
```

---

On a blank project (without a master page template), if `<o:viewParam>` is used as follows.

```xhtml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <f:metadata>
            <o:viewParam name="id" value="#{testManagedBean.id}" required="false"/>
        </f:metadata>

        <h:form>
            <h:inputText value="#{testManagedBean.text}"/>
            <h:commandButton value="Submit"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

consider the above mentioned **CDI** bean with just an extra property `id` of type String, it throws the following exception.

```
01:42:54,890 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-47) JSF1068: Cannot instantiate component with component-type org.omnifaces.component.input.ViewParam
01:42:54,890 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-47) UT005023: Exception handling request to /Test-war/Test.xhtml: javax.servlet.ServletException: Expression Error: Named Object: org.omnifaces.component.input.ViewParam not found.
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: org.omnifaces.component.input.ViewParam not found.
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponentApplyAnnotations(ApplicationImpl.java:1933) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:1168) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.createComponent(ApplicationWrapper.java:637) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.ForwardingApplication.createComponent(ForwardingApplication.java:111) [wildfly-jsf-injection-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.createComponent(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:584) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.MetadataHandler.apply(MetadataHandler.java:104) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewMetadataImpl.createMetadataView(ViewMetadataImpl.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:241) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    ... 26 more
```

Replacing `<o:viewParam>` by `<f:viewParam>` suppresses the above exception.

---

<sub>I do not know, if this may work on a higher version of JSF, since I still do not know how to change a JSF version in WildFly (8.1.0 final) (it uses JSF 2.2.6 as default). Unlike GlassFish, there is no `javax.faces.jar` file I can see somewhere in a server directory that can be replaced with a newer JSF version. A different jar file is seen in the directory - `${ServerLocation}/modules/system/layers/base/javax/faces/api/main` which is `jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar`.</sub>

Comment: Are you sure you're not enabling CDI in your project?

Comment: Yes I still do not use CDI anywhere (I decided to use a few months ago but gave it up because of a [bug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23583479/1391249)).

Comment: Well, from BalusC's answer, seems like CDI is auto enabled in Java EE 7. You should probably look in a way to disable CDI inspection for your project.

Comment: I had the same problem and get resolved using the below solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756707/how-to-disable-weld-on-wildfly

Comment: @jerith2 : Thank you. The problem is however, [also](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26447519/1391249) associated somewhere else. I also tried out CDI beans already but to no avail. This only works for small toy projects but not for complex projects. It is something that cannot be expressed linguistically. I abandoned WildFly and stick to GlassFish Server (4.1) as of now - planning to use Apache TomEE in the future. Any comment(s)/answer(s) on this post or that linked question are awaiting curiously/eagerly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by replacing @ManagedBean and annotations in javax.faces.bean.* by @Named and annotations in javax.enterprise.context.*.

Comment: The question is now obsolete in which the root cause was completely unidentifiable / unrecognizable. Superficially, the problem was arriving from the WildFly-NetBeans plugin which now somehow [hesitatingly works](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33892879/1391249) with the latest version of NetBeans (8.1).