# Using the WildFly application server with NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, wildfly, wildfly-8, netbeans-8

I was accustomed to using GlassFish server all the times. I'm migrating a Java EE application from GlassFish (4.0) to WildFly 8.1.0 final.

I tried using WildFly 8.1.0 final on NetBeans 8.0 using [this plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/53333/wildfly-application-server) for the server, since there was no built-in plugin for the server.

Unlike GlassFish, the application is however, not deployed on saving project data even though the *deploy on save* option on the IDE is enabled. The application leads to very strange/unknown/unusual problems. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26433574/1391249) is full of (merely) some of those problems.

I upgraded NetBeans to 8.0.1 (with JSF to 2.2.8-02) which has a built-in WildFly-Plugin but it also brought all most no difference anyway than the previous version of the IDE.

In [this comment](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=243502#c15) of a bug report, it is mentioned that a fix was made by changing/adding some XML corresponding to a JDBC driver as follows,

```xml
<driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
  <xa-datasource-class>
    com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
  </xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

I also made this change to the `standalone-full.xml` file. This particular part looks like as follows.

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
    <datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
            <driver>h2</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>sa</user-name>
                <password>sa</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>

        <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/project_datasource" pool-name="project_datasource" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
            <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectdb</connection-url>
            <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
            <driver>mysql</driver>
            <pool>
                <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>15</max-pool-size>
            </pool>
            <security>
                <user-name>root</user-name>
                <password>root</password>
            </security>
            <validation>
                <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                <background-validation>false</background-validation>
            </validation>
            <statement>
                <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
            </statement>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
            <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
    </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

But all in vain. Doing so made nothing new.

Anyway, is it possible to use WildFly (8.1.0 or higher, whenever available) with NetBeans for now (maybe by making somewhere some changes)?

It appears that I'm almost left with staying away with WildFly for now. Is it? :)

<sub>I do not precisely know whether the plugin is the problem or not. It might be something different.</sub>

---

**Update :**

It took me at least three weeks to encounter this situation. So, please do not think that the entire thing I wrote here is wrong/meaningless, if you could not reproduce the same thing just within a moment (as mentioned in the linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26433574/1391249) - including the strike-through text) - I just cannot say anything more about it.

One of the reproducible things : if some changes to an existing application are made, the application is not (automatically) deployed to the server, if those changes are saved (not to mention that the **deploy on save** option is enabled in the IDE) - but that's just one simplest thing and cannot be relied upon, even though happens correctly.

Apparently the plugin does not interact/communicate with the IDE in a way that it should (as happens correctly, when using GlassFish Server, for example).

Answer (score 3):

Just a warning, as I missed this and was tearing my hair out on this.
Wildfly uses port 9990 for debug management as default, this however causes a problem if you have an Nvidia device as the Nvidia network service also uses 9990.

To fix it, I've stopped the Nvidia network service (In task manager) and my Netbeans (8.1) can now connect to the wildfly server and no longer falls over.

You can also change the ports that wildfly uses, to stop the conflict. If you are using the standalone.xml file, change the following line:

```
<socket-binding name="management-http"
    interface="management"
    port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
```

And change the port number to your choosing. Now in NetBeans, when you choose to add the server and get to the Instance Properties, make sure you set the management port to the same as what you have set in the config file. I chose 9991 and had no issues so far.

(I posted here as this was the first result I kept coming to when searching for fixing the issue)

Comment: WildFly runs correctly unless there is a complex sizable application to run (having several dependencies). Anyway, I cannot comment anything about it as I gave up that server and did not try anything since then.

Comment: Does "Deploy on Save" happen correctly using NetBeans 8.1 / WildFly 9.0.2 final? I see the IDE does not automatically deploy the project, whenever changes are saved at least in standard NetBeans projects (which do not use Apache Maven as a build and dependency management tool). It appears that the plugin fails to communicate with the server. (I have just created a simple test application using NetBeans 8.1 / WildFly 9.0.2 final having only one XHTML file with no additional dependencies other than PrimeFaces. The "Deploy on Save" option is enabled on the IDE).

Comment: The single page EE application runs correctly on this test application but it causes problems at long run as mentioned in the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26433574/1391249), when the application gets more complex having several dependencies. (I also made the change as you mentioned in the `standalone.xml` file)

Comment: I created a JDBC connection pool in WildFly 9.0.2 final. It successfully communicates with the associated database through an EE application using EJB/JPA (Hibernate) and JSF as a client. The problem occurs, when several dependencies are added to the project in which case, the plugin certainly fails to properly communicate with the server. Among others, "Deploy on Save" never happens in either case. It always requires a hard deploy.

Answer (score 1):

I'd encourage you to file a bug at:

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=serverplugins

and use WildFly as the category.

Have you tried running WildFly using a CLI and see if your IDE related problems go away ?

Comment: [Done](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=248161). CLI has a steep learning curve. I tried using WildFly first time. Therefore, I'm not able to do it using CLI (I merely copy/pasted some CLI commands from your [blog](http://wildfly.org/news/2014/02/06/GlassFish-to-WildFly-migration/)). Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks!

A slightly more detailed tutorial on jboss-cli is at:

https://github.com/arun-gupta/wildfly-lab/blob/master/docs/chapters/jboss-cli.adoc

Answer (score 1):

First the wildFly plugin is distributed withe the Netbeans IDE 8.0.1 so the plugin you're using might be deprecated.
Like Arun said, fill a bug with netbeans log / wildfly log and your config.
There was an NPE in the parsing when the driver was defined in the datasource by its driver-class.

Comment: I used the plugin which is bundled with Netbeans IDE 8.0.1 (not the stray plugin which I just tried with Netbeans IDE 8.0 and thew away).