# Jsf implementation version NullPointerException when migrating from Tomcat 7 to 8

Tags: maven, jsf, tomcat, icefaces, tomcat8

I am currently using JSF 2.2.7 and Icefaces version 4.0.0. My project was running on Tomcat 7, but I am having trouble trying to get it working on Tomcat 8. I am getting a null pointer exception as a method in the icefaces code seems to check the current version of jsf being used. This always return null and i do not seem to be setting the correct implementation of jsf. The stack trace is as follows:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.icefaces.util.EnvUtils.isJSF22(EnvUtils.java:976)     at
>   org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMPartialViewContext.renderState(DOMPartialViewContext.java:743)
>     at
>   org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMPartialViewContext.processPartial(DOMPartialViewContext.java:301)
>     at
>   javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004) 
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:430)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
>     at
>   javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) 
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) 
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)  Aug 04, 2015 7:50:52 AM
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy
>   handleRenderException  SEVERE: Error Rendering
>   View[/pages/Ports.xhtml]  java.lang.NullPointerException      at
>   org.icefaces.util.EnvUtils.isJSF22(EnvUtils.java:976)     at
>   org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMPartialViewContext.renderState(DOMPartialViewContext.java:743)
>     at
>   org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMPartialViewContext.processPartial(DOMPartialViewContext.java:301)
>     at
>   javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004) 
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:430)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
>     at
>   javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) 
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) 
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)  Aug 04, 2015 7:50:52 AM
>   com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl
>   handlePartialResponseError  SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException 
>     at org.icefaces.util.EnvUtils.isJSF22(EnvUtils.java:976)    at
>   org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMPartialViewContext.renderState(DOMPartialViewContext.java:743)
>     at
>   org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMPartialViewContext.processPartial(DOMPartialViewContext.java:301)
>     at
>   javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004) 
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:430)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
>     at
>   javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) 
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) 
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

On closer inspection it seems that the getImplementationVersion() method is returning null:

```
/**
 * Determine whether the current JSF implementation is version 2.2
 * @return true if JSF implementation is 2.2
 */
public static boolean isJSF22() {
    return FacesContext.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion().startsWith("2.2");
}
```

Here is my pom.xml with the IceFaces and JSF dependencies. I am unsure how my JSF implementation is not set.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <project
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>oag.com.reference</groupId>
        <artifactId>web</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>ReferenceDataWeb </name>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <description>Reference data web project.</description>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.0.201403182114</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>icefaces</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>icefaces-ace</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.icepush</groupId>
            <artifactId>icepush</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>icefaces-compat</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oag.reference</groupId>
            <artifactId>business</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.icefaces.ace-themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ace-cupertino</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.7</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>

 </project>
```

This is the complete list of jar files creates in my war file WEB-INF/lib folder:

> ace-cupertino-4.0.0.jar
>    activation-1.1.jar 
>   business-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
>   commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
>   commons-logging-1.1.jar 
>   database-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   db2jcc4-1.0.0.jar
>   hamcrest-core-1.1.jar 
>   icefaces-4.0.0.jar 
>   icefaces-ace-4.0.0.jar
>   icepush-4.0.0.jar 
>   javax.faces-2.2.7.jar
>   jstl-1.2.jar 
>   junit-4.9.jar
>   mail-1.4.1.jar 
>   mockito-all-1.9.5.jar
>   poi-3.7.jar

Looking inside the javax.faces-2.2.7.jar and META-INF/MANIFEST.MF i can see that the implementation version is set to 2.2.7. So I have no idea how the implementation version is null when referenced by the icefaces code at runtime.

Can anybody help please?

Thanks - See more at: http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/22974.page#80376

Comment: Try current Mojarra version 2.2.12 instead. There was a Tomcat-related fix in setting right context class loader somewhere after 2.2.7.

Comment: Hi, I have changed both com.sun.faces dependencies in my pom.xml file to version 2.2.12 as suggested. This has prevented my initial problems but created some more. I now receive an INFO warning that "INFO: CDI @ViewScoped bean functionality unavailable" and a javax.faces.FacesException when trying to view an xhtml page. This exception says...Cannot add the same component twice: javascript_runner.  Thanks, Liam.

Comment: Great, your problem is solved. The INFO is innocent/informal. The exception is candidate for a new question if you can't figure out it (hint: stop binding components to beans)

Comment: Thanks for your help regarding the initial problem! I am not sure what you mean by your last comment. I have not used the binding attribute to bind a component to any bean in the project.

Comment: Perhaps ICEfaces is internally doing that. Can't tell for sure as I don't use it. This issue may provide insight (for ICEfaces guys): https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2894

Comment: By the way, in future questions please post stack traces in code block instead of quote block as they can get long and really need scrollbars and whitespace preserved to maintain readability. You have to copy-paste it once again because it can't be fixed by re-editing (all whitespace is already gone due to the quote formatting)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have posted on the Icefaces forum: http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/22976.page#sthash.wDydtdN4.dpbs. In regards to the format of my question.. I was having problems with code indentations and was unable to post the question (hence resorting to block quotes). Thanks.

Comment: Next time, paste stack trace, select it again and press Ctrl+K (or press `{}` button in editor toolbar)

Comment: With help of the detail in your question over there I found http://jira.icesoft.org/browse/ICE-10335 which says this problem is already acknowledged as ICEfaces bug and fixed in 4.1. So .. You also need to upgrade that :)

Comment: Thank you once again, you are the best! :) I dont think that Icefaces 4.1 has been released yet. Well, I cant find a maven dependency for it anyway. I will have to do some digging!

Comment: I see that snapshot releases are available here http://anonsvn.icesoft.org/repo/maven2/snapshots/org/icefaces/icefaces/4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Apologies for my lack of understanding (holding on to the excuse that im still an intern), but how would I incorporate this in my project? Do I need to download the jar and place this within my lib folder manually or can i add the snapshot release to my pom.xml like so....
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
   <artifactId>icefaces</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>

Comment: You basically need to explicitly add snapshot repository as a new repository to pom. Be careful though when using snapshots in production. You'd rather pin a fixed snapshot version (which is easier if you have your own build/CI system).

Comment: Right I have done that, do I then remove the icefaces dependencies that I was using previously?

Comment: Taking your advise, I have downloaded the bundle-parent-4.1.0-20141115.001413-1.pom from the snapshot repositories http://sventon.icesoft.org/svn/repos/repo/list/maven2/snapshots/org/icefaces/bundle-parent/4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/. I have then added this to an artifactory so that i have a fixed snapshot. The artifactory then produces a dependency for me to add to my pom.xml. After adding this, icefaces jars fail to download to my lib folder. Please can you take a look at my icefaces forum question: http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/22976.page#sthash.dqvoDs5t.dpbs.  Your help is much appreciated,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely caused by a bug of having the wrong context class loader at hands which was fixed in Mojarra 2.2.9 as per [issue 3341](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3341).

Upgrading to at least Mojarra 2.2.9 (currently latest is 2.2.12) should solve your problem.