# JSF throwing exception in cluster environment - Component ID j_idt311 has already been found in the view.

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish, cluster-computing

I'm running GlassFish 3.1.2.2 in fail-over cluster. Session replication is configured and works perfectly. Project is in JSF and PrimeFaces using extensive AJAX. The problem is when server fails-over to another node on AJAX call I'm getting the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID j_idt311 has already been found in the view.  
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:846)
    at .....
```

Manually assigning IDs to every component on every page is impractical. Is there way to resolve the problem in more practical way?
Thank you.

Comment: This problem can have many causes. Let's start with excluding the most common starter's mistakes. Can you assure that you're **nowhere** using the `binding` attribute on a view or broader scoped bean property, and that you've **nowhere** declared an `UIComponent` instance as a property of a view or broader scoped bean?

Comment: No, nothing special, no binding, just standard components

Comment: Is the Mojarra-specific `web.xml` context param `com.sun.faces.serializeServerState` set to `true`?

Comment: I just tried to set that param, it didn't help.

Comment: Are you using GF 3.1.2.2 builtin Mojarra version (which is rather old these days) or did you [upgrade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782528/how-to-update-mojarra-version-in-glassfish) it to latest 2.1.x available?

Comment: Yes, I had buildin Mojarra version 2.1.6. I upgraded to latest (2.1.29) - still getting same error.

Comment: I think I got it to work by upgrading Mojarra to 2.1.29, setting com.sun.faces.serializeServerState=true and [patching](http://www.ninthavenue.com.au/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-el-lang-variablemapperimpl-fixed-for-glassfish-jsf) JSF bug triggered by serializeServerState=true setting.