# Which settings are needed to make use of EL 3 in a JavaEE environment?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, el, jsf-2.2

I am using [Apache TomEE 1.7.4](http://tomee.apache.org/index.html).

The dependencies added in my `pom.xml` file are-

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

To make use of the `new string concatenation operator +=` like in -

```
 <h:graphicImage 
   value="#{resource[facesContext.viewRoot.locale+='/default:img/rafa.png']}"/>
```

I replaced the EL 2.2 version with this-

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
         </dependency>
```

But i am getting a -

```
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [#{resource[facesContext.viewRoot.locale+='/default:img/rafa.png']}]
    at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(ExpressionBuilder.java:145)
    at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:171)
    at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createValueExpression(ExpressionBuilder.java:216)
    at org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.createValueExpression(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.webbeans.el22.WrappedExpressionFactory.createValueExpression(WrappedExpressionFactory.java:59)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getValueExpression(TagAttributeImpl.java:408)
    ... 43 more
```

Suggestions, if any?

I am not sure whether I will have to upgrade to version 8 since,

> Apache Tomcat 8 supports the Java Servlet 3.1, JavaServer Pages 2.3,
>   Java Unified Expression Language 3.0 and Java API for WebSocket 1.1
>   specifications.

---

OKay, it works perfect with `GlassFish(4.0) Java EE Application Server`.
But what I don't understand which entries to be made in pom.xml file-

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info), it is mentioned that the below dependency needs to be added in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version><!-- 7.0 (JSF 2.2) or 6.0 (JSF 2.0/2.1) --></version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

After adding it, there is-

[image]

A screenshot to illustrate my confusion-

In the server logs, i found that the server is using this version of Mojarra

> 2016-06-08T17:26:36.778+0530|INFO: Initializing `Mojarra 2.2.0` (
>   20130502-2118 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0@11930)

with the lib folder of Glassfish 4.0 -
[image]

You see there is a jar file `javaee`.

If I need to use the `Mojarra 2.2.6` version, say for example, what exactly I need to do?

Comment: Your Maven config is not correct. Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8081234 (and "Installing JSF" in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)

Comment: @BalusC: The JSF info page suggests for (AS + Maven) users to add this to the pom.xml file- `<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version><!-- 7.0 (JSF 2.2) or 6.0 (JSF 2.0/2.1) --></version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>`, with `scope` provided. Since Apache TomEE will be shipping with Myfaces implementation, please suggest or do I need to make use of Apache TomEE PLUME for Mojarra support.

Comment: You should basically replace libraries in server itself, not provide via webapp. Or replace the whole server itself, indeed.

Comment: @BalusC: Replace the whole server itself by WHICH server? Didn't get your point. Secondly, replace libraries in server itself, do you mean replacing jars present in lib folder of Apache-TomEE-webprofile-1.7.4\lib. My confusion being that I haven't worked with AS. :)

Comment: 1) By the one bundling Mojarra. 2) That's correct. Perhaps more things need to be done or taken into account, this depends on server itself. In e.g. WildFly it's a bit more work than just swapping out JARs.

Comment: @BalusC: It works fine with Glassfish. Please suggest on the updated part of the question.

Comment: That's answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782528/how-to-update-mojarra-version-in-glassfish (by the way, GF 4.0 is full of childhood diseases -all the hassle to get "first Java EE 7" server ready on time. Grab latest one, which is IIRC 4.1.1, or just get Payara).

Comment: @BalusC: And the first part in the updated question, I mean the JSF info suggested to add the dependency (see above), & there is a javaee jar file in glassfish lib folder. Which one will get precedence? Or are the 2 jars exactly same?

Comment: The jar file specified in the maven pom.xml is only used to compile your application - it is not used at runtime. That is what `<scope>provided</scope> means. At runtime your server implementation (whatever it may be) is used.

Comment: @SteveC: Thanks Steve for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

MyFaces supports to configure the EL ExpressionFactory to use (https://myfaces.apache.org/core20/myfaces-impl/webconfig.html) so it can be one way to enforce one impl but you can also upgrade to TomEE 7 which packages Tomcat 8.